# Choosing LEDs/resistors to drive directly from 3v3 HC CMOS logic

Tags: led, cmos

I'm building a home-brew CPU and I would like to add some blinkenlights, to show the logic state of various signals.  (It will run at 1Hz - 100kHz.)

Can I directly drive an LED from a 3v3 74HCxxx output (with a fanout of 1-3)?

If so, what can I get away with regarding LED colours and current-limiting resistors?

Comment: The key thing to do here is to look at the datasheet for your 74HCxxx part, and see how much current it can source (or sink, depending on your desired led configuration). If it can handle the 1-2mA you need for an led, you're good to go, just take its output voltage, subtract the led voltage, and calculate your resistor from there.

Answer (score 2):

With 3.3V systems it is often a good idea to supply bells and whistles like LEDs with their own power rail and drive them with open-collector outputs or discrete transistor drivers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBRnTb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a number of benefits to this method including.

1. Ability to use larger voltage LEDs.
2. Reduced demand on the 3.3V supply. Possibly allowing a much smaller regulator.
3. Increased resistor size provides more uniformity in LED current over LED forward voltage variations.
4. Gives you the option to turn off ALL the bells and whistles when in sleep mode.
5. In battery operated circuits, LEDS get dimmer as the battery begins to die giving you a free bonus feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are driving the LEDs with the same output that is connected to CMOS inputs you need to stay within the limits of current. You will do better to have the LED on with the logic level low.

From the [74HC00 datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC00A-D.PDF): (the different columns are different max temperatures)

[image]

If you sink 4mA the output voltage with a 4.5V supply (think 5V minus 10%) is 0.33V maximum. If you source 4mA the voltage drop from the 4.5V supply is 0.66V maximum (double), so the noise immunity will be reduced..  1.02V vs. 0.69V minimum.

It would be better if you could use something like 2mA rather than 4mA (still plenty for a modern indicator LED- don't buy the crappiest LEDs you can find).

Say you design with 2mA- if the supply is 5V and the LED drops about 2V (red) or 3V (most other colors) you would use a resistor of 1.5K or 1K. Those are approximate, but should be fine.

CMOS inputs don't draw significant current, so the fanout is pretty much irrelevant at DC but you will get slowing of the edges as you add loading plus capacitance.

Edit: I see from the title that you're planning on using 3.3V- the drive capacity of 74HC logic is much less at 3V than at 5V-- and the resistors get more fiddly since there is little voltage to work with for the resistor. Suggest you rethink the supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

As you should know, the current driving an LED is limited by Ohm's Law the total series resistance in the loop I=ΔV/R where ΔV, the voltage difference is between Vdd and Vth or what you may call the dim threshold of an LED ( e.g. 10% of rated I) where ΔV/ΔI becomes somewhat linear.

You can apply Ohm's law to CMOS logic or any semiconductor when conducting towards rated current and determine its equivalent DC driver impedance from the datasheet specs for Vol and (Vdd-Voh) vs Iout to get the  incremental ESR.

\$ ESR = Rs =\Delta V/\Delta I=RdsOn \$
 \$
 _{( for \ any\ MOSFET \ or\  CMOS\ or \ diode\ or \ LED \ or  \ BJT(saturated) = 
r_{_{CE}} \ \ )}  \$

### (By design standards) I use this rule of thumb:

- 74ALVCxx is 25 Ω  @3.3V +/-25% or so for worst case
- 74HCxx is  50 Ω  @5V +/-25% worst case

  - and 100Ω  @3.3V

    - 130 Ω  at 3.0V

I'll leave you to verify this on your own.

---

Using @Spehro 's datasheet  @3.0V using typ values to check my memory :)

for \$ESR=ΔV/ΔI= \frac{V_{OL}}{I_{OL}}= \frac {0.33V}{2.4mA} =135 \ Ω  \$ @3.0V

- \$  \frac{0.33}{4.5mA}= 73 Ω \$  @4.5V
- \$  \frac{0.33}{6.0 mA}= 55 Ω \$  @6.5V

---

Next I know that ESR of all diodes and LEDs ~ k/Pd with k=1 (+/-25% typ) for 3V LED's for example 5mm white/blue/green LEDs have an ESR ~ 15 Ω because Pd rated =65mW and 1/65mW ~ 15  Ω (and verified from decades of experience this is a rule of thumb)

### So what is your LED current using 74ALVCxx @3.3V?  (depends on colour and LED power rating Pd)

if you use a 74ALVCxx @3.,3V with 25 Ω and a 5mm White Led with 15 Ω ESR and a threshold voltage of ~2.8V ( where Vf = Vth + ESR*I)

example

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxpSXf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Assumptions

- Only using High Bright HB good quality LED's not old ones with Vf from 3 to 3.6V
- RdsOn for CMOS logic is fairly well matched for Pch and Nch ESR
- you know how to use Ohm's Law

Comment: This does not apply to LEDSTRIPs which have Rs on flex strip. and if you are consider 3W LEDs , the very best white LEDs have k=0.5 so ESR=0.5/3W = 1.7Ω  and for 5mm Red/Yellow, Vth=1.8 and Vf=2~2.2V@20mA and ESR ~10 Ω for 65mW rating or k=0.65